# What is wrong with this script that is supposed to test the Collatz Conjecture?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to make a script that tests the Collatz Conjecture. More specifically, the goal is to make a script that allows me to enter a positive integer that is not 1, and prints out the final number when the Collatz algorithm is finished, which I expect will be 1.

Take any positive integer n. If n is even, divide n by 2 to get n / 2. If n is odd, multiply n by 3 and add 1 to get 3n + 1. Repeat the process indefinitely. The conjecture states that no matter which number you start with, you will always reach 1 eventually.

This is my attempt -

```
echo "Enter in a positive integer greater than 1"
read n
let "r=$n%2"
if [ $n -le 1 ]
then
echo "Error: you must enter in a positive integer greater than 1"
exit
fi
while [ $n -ne 1 ]
do
    if [ $r == 0 ]
    then
          let "n=$n/2"
          echo $n
    fi

    if [ $r -ne 0 ]
    then
          let "n=3*$n + 1"
          echo $n
    fi
done

echo $n
```

When I type in 2, I get 1, which is the desired result. However, when I read in the value of 3, I get an infinite loop that looks like this:

```
931947686741790850
2795843060225372551
8387529180676117654
6715843468318801347
1700786331246852426
5102358993740557279
-3139667092487879778
9027742796245912283

.
.
.
```

And so on.

My exact question is: **What is wrong with my code? What is causing it to print huge numbers?**

Comment: @Stalin Vignesh Kumar, when you do edits like that, please remove the extra empty lines too

Comment: please have a look at the editing help, and the first item about marking code blocks: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: @ilkkachu Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
let "r=$n%2"
...
while [ $n -ne 1 ]
do
    if [ $r == 0 ]
    ...
done
```

You're only assigning to `r` once, outside the loop.

In most programming languages, an assignment like `y = f(x)` means "Take the current value of `x`, calculate `f(x)` using it, and copy the result to `y`". That's not the same as the mathematics interpretation which would be more like "From here and forever, `y` shall always equal `f(x)`". Note that with `n` in your code, it couldn't even work like that: you're modifying its value and relying on it being different in different iterations of the loop.

So whatever value `r` gets from the initial number, it keeps for the whole loop, and you repeat the same operation for each iteration of the loop. The one with tripling of course just runs away to huge numbers and then starts overflowing.

The fix is simple, move the assignment to `r` inside the loop to have it recalculated every time `n` changes.

<sub>You also have the common issue of unquoted variable expansions, but they're not your problem here.</sub>

Comment: You solved my problem. Thanks.